# Getting list of checked radiobuttons in .net

Tags: c#, .net

TLDR; Looking for a method to retrieve all radiobuttons by means of something like this... (psudo)

```
    List<RadioButton> btn = new List<RadioButton>;
    btn = stackPanel.getAllRadioButtons()
```

I am currently building a little quiz application in C#. I have functions that add the required GUI elements to a groupbox. I would like to know if there is any way that I can loop through the created elements (for instance radio buttons) to see which are checked.

Here is one of the functions along with how they are added to the window.

```
    private void tfQ(string questionBody)
    {
        StackPanel questionPanel = new StackPanel{Orientation = Orientation.Vertical};
        questionPanel.Children.Add(new Label { Content = questionBody });
        GroupBox group = new GroupBox();
        RadioButton trueRadio = new RadioButton();
        trueRadio.Content = "True";
        RadioButton falseRadio = new RadioButton();
        falseRadio.Content = "False";
        questionPanel.Children.Add(trueRadio);
        questionPanel.Children.Add(falseRadio);
        group.Content = questionPanel;
        mainStack.Children.Add(group);


    }
```

Constructor:

```
    public quiz()
    {
        tfQ("This is a true/false question");
        Window w = new Window();
        w.Content = mainStack;
        w.Show();
    }
```

I have found many ways to do it in the C# scripting format

(using the Control function ...)

```
     var checkedButton = container.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>()
                                  .FirstOrDefault(r => r.Checked);
```

but I have not yet found a "programmatic" way of doing it. I have considered changing the type of void tfQ to a StackPanel, but that only helps me to easier loop through the stack panels, althought that only partly solves me problem - allows me to easier loop through the StackPanels but I still don't know how to get the RadioButtons on a panel.

P.S I am very new to C# - with experience in Java/C/C++/Python

Comment: `OfType` is not searching recursively. But instead of writing a method that does it,  i'd suggest to make the `questionPanel` a field in your class not a local variable in the method. Then you can use this code to retrieve all your checked RadioButtons:  `IEnumerable<RadioButton> checkedRadioButtons = _questionPanel.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().Where(rb => rb.Checked);`. You can enumerate them in a `foreach` or use `ToList` to create a `List<RadioButton>`.

Comment: I find searching for a control is very slow.  So instead I find adding the controls to a list as you create them is faster.

Comment: @jdweng: you don't need to search through the whole page. just use the direct container control, `questionPanel` in this case, then it's not slow and you don't need another collection(`questionPanel.Controls` is the first). If you still notice a performance issue it's not related to this.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I managed to fix the problem by making use of casting. It seems I misunderstood how control elements work.

Answer (score 0):

I made use of the following code to cast the content into a new groupbox and stackpanel, respectively.

```
    if (child is GroupBox)
    {
       if ((child as GroupBox).Content is StackPanel)
       {
           StackPanel d = (StackPanel)((GroupBox)child).Content; 
       }

     }
```

This allowed me to cast the content into a local copy of a control. It may not be the best way - I'm sure it is very inefficient to be honest. Solved the problem.